# Get Hex value from LAB color space

Tags: python, scikit-image

How to get Hex from LAB color space?

There is an online converter https://www.nixsensor.com/free-color-converter/, but I need an automatic call.

I tried to use https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.lab2rgb function to get RBG color space and then convert to Hex, using colormap.rgb2hex for instance.

How do I call the lab2rgb function? It receives an image as an array.

Example:

LAB values: [94.4, -1.22, -0.13]
Return Hex value:  #ECF0EF

```
from skimage import color

lab_color = [[[94.4, -1.22, -0.13]]]
rgb_color = color.lab2rgb(lab_color, illuminant='D65', observer='2')
print(rgb_color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there, you just omitted scaling up to the range 0..255

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from skimage import color

# Define a Lab colour
lab_color = [[[94.4, -1.22, -0.13]]]

# Convert to RGB and extract R,G and B components, then scale to 0..255
rgb_color = color.lab2rgb(lab_color, illuminant='D65', observer='2')
r = round(rgb_color[0,0,0] * 255)
g = round(rgb_color[0,0,1] * 255)
b = round(rgb_color[0,0,2] * 255)

# Format up as hex string, i.e. #ECF0EF
res = f'#{r:02X}{g:02X}{b:02X}'
```